# How effective is speeding?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics, everyday-life

At a simple level, speeding in a car attempts to minimize the time required to travel a distance by utilizing the basic relationship: $$d=st$$

So for a given distance, time should be inversely proportional to speed: the faster you go the less time it takes.

My question is, on a practical level, does this actually help you get to your destination much faster? Say you are travelling, on average, 5 mph (sorry for non SI units, as an American driving in kph just seems wrong) over the speed limit, which is often considered 'safe' for avoiding a traffic ticket. Does this shave seconds off your commute time? Minutes?

I believe that traffic can be modeled using fluid dynamics (haven't actually seen those models myself just have been told this is the case) so, how does this come to in to play while speeding? It seems to me that it would depend on *where* you speed rather than how fast, i.e. speeding to avoiding getting stuck at a traffic light.

Any insights or calculations would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: How far you're driving and what the speed limit is would make a big difference too if you're looking for when a 5 mph difference would achieve a perceptibly earlier arrival.

Comment: Right, 5 mph is a big difference if the speed limit is 25 and not as much if its 65. And I also understand that distance is a large factor which is why I have never really worked out this problem for myself. Every answer I came to really was "it depends".

Comment: FYI nobody here particularly cares what unit system you use (so, SI or not, it doesn't matter).

Comment: How is this related to fluid dynamics? Traffic flow is modeled similar to fluid dynamics when there are many many cars, driving on roads which fork, merge, turn, etc. If you're just looking to know how much time you can save by going, say, 5 mph above the speed limit, the answer is a trivial extension of the equation you've mentioned in your question.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I assume that's exactly how the question is related to fluid dynamics - that is, jkeuhlen wants to know whether the effect of speeding (when possible) by a few MPH is worthwhile when you take traffic flow into account. jkeuhlen, can you confirm this? (Otherwise, it would be an incredibly lazy question!) I do think some clarifying edits are in order, though; for example, what sort of traffic flow should be considered? Highway traffic or city traffic? Rush hour? etc.

Comment: Exactly, I know about some _mass transport models_ being employed for modelling traffic flow, but _fluid dynamics_ !!! For the kind of stop-start-bump traffic we have in a typical metro city?

Comment: I'm with @PranavHosangadi - I don't see fluid dynamics here. If you're *capable* of speeding, then there is no traffic flow issue. If there is obstructing traffic, then you can't choose your speed, so asking what speed to choose doesn't make any sense.

Comment: In some cities, [the traffic lights are timed so that when you drive down the main roads slightly below speed limit, they will always be green](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_wave). Driving faster is pointless, because you will just spend the time you gained waiting at traffic lights.

Comment: Just an FYI: For Canada, it's `Km/h`, not `kph`.

Comment: @Philipp as someone who does that for a living I can tell you not most lights aren't coordinated that way (either due to technical glitches or an official never turning it on), and the green wave doesn't take into account freeways (where you won't see a light for miles)

Comment: Do you regularly drive on a flat, straight empty road? The real life is some many more times more complex than you can write down with a few simple equations.

Comment: BTW Speed limits have nothing to do with safety as driving in Europe indicates.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I can't speak to the appropriateness of fluid dynamics, but surely you've seen some nutjob weaving in and out of traffic and creating a hazard for everyone doing his best to speed. Perhaps that's what the OP has in mind?

Comment: Why do you assume the point of speeding is to get there faster?  It might be, but it might not, too.  Generally speaking, I speed because it feels better.  I find piddling along at a ridiculously low speed that hasn't changed since cars were steel boxes with no safety features annoying, so I drive faster.  It's about enjoying my time on the road (or at least, being *less* annoyed by it), not about getting where I'm going faster.

Comment: One point to note on all this is that whereas fluids speed up when they encounter an aperture, traffic slows down. If traffic were a fluid, when 2 lanes of a highway were shut, the remaining lane (in England where we have midget roads) would have cars travelling through it at 210 mph to conserve the flow; whereas in reality the opposite happens. Is this the kind of aspect you're concerned with in your question?

Comment: when using a fluid model to describe traffic temperature corresponds to number of accidents.

Comment: It's more important to minimize time spent going slow than to go fast.

Comment: Speeding more depends arguably on when you do it and where you are going. Not really on where you are at that moment. Say you are going to work. Odds are you'll get stuck in traffic at less than the limit, but let's ignore that. If you speed a bit to beat some of the lights, you might shave up to 10-15 minutes off your trip (more and you really should have taken the highway). Then you get to work early (if the saved 15 min makes you just on time, you should have left earlier anyway just in case). So what? 15 min of work extra? You leave at the same time at the end. How is anything different?

Comment: Speeding to get home. Why? so you can get 10-15 minutes of more sleep? However, if it's a time-sensitive destination, that's different

Comment: Wife having a baby? House on fire? Fell asleep at your desk and the puck's about to drop in 5 minutes? Then speeding helps.

Comment: Pretty much anything hockey-related is a good reason to speed. (Yeah, I'm Canadian too. Where the top speed limit is 100, which is a much better number than 60. mph just seems silly; how many feet per hour is 60mph without using a calculator?)

Comment: @Jim Approximately 60 miles worth.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy you win this round

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Alright, let's start with your direct question.  Since $d = vt$ the time it takes to travel a certain distance is inversely proportional to your speed $ t \propto v^{-1} $, and so the fractional change in time is proportional to the negative fractional change in your speed.

$$ \frac{dt}{t} = - \frac{dv}{v} $$
So, if we consider typical a typical highway speed of 65 mph and a 5 mph difference, this is a fractional change of about 8%.  So going 5 mph faster on the highway will shave 8% off your travel time.  So if you had an hour drive, it'll shave off 5 minutes.

### Drag

But. Let's try to consider the added cost of going faster.  If you go faster, the wind drag is higher, so your car needs more power to maintain speed.  More power means more energy, more energy means more fuel, more fuel means more money.

If we consider just the contribution of wind resistance, we know that $ F \propto v^2 $ for cars, and power is $ P = F v $ so the power consumed by drag goes as $ P \propto v^3 $.  Energy consumption is $ E = P t $, so if we consider a drive of fixed length, since $ t \propto v^{-1}$ we have for the contribution of air drag, $ E \propto v^2 $.  Now, the energy you get from fuel is proportional to the number of gallons you buy, and the cost scales as the number of gallons so $ \text{fuel cost} \propto v^2 $.  So the fractional change in the fuel consumed due to wind drag is:
$$ \frac{ d(\text{fuel cost}_{\text{drag}} ) }{ \text{ fuel cost}_{\text{drag}} } = 2 \frac{ dv }{ v } $$
So, for the same 8% increase in speed, you pay an additional 16% in fuel costs due to the loss to air drag.

Naturally air drag isn't the only way we use up fuel to keep a car running, there are all kinds of losses in a car, from inefficiencies in the engine itself, to friction in the various components of the engine, etc.  As a simple model, let's say that the power a car consumes is the sum of the air drag and a constant term independent of speed: $P \sim \alpha v^3 + \beta $ for some appropriate choices of $\alpha$ and $\beta$  This would mean that our energy consumption would still be $ E = P t $, so for a constant distance drive, we're talking
$$ E \sim \alpha v^2 + \frac{\beta}{v} $$.  We can test this model against data from a government study (figure from [wikipedia:Fuel_economy_in_automobiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_economy_in_automobiles)) where for our model, we have 
$$ \text{mpg} = \frac{ \alpha }{ v^2 + \frac{\beta}{v} } $$

Here I've shown the figure as well as an example fit of our model:

[image: Observed mpg versus speed and fit]

The fit is overlayed in red, and corresponds to $\alpha = 1.5 \times 10^5, \beta = 1.28 \times 10^5 $.  Notice that our simple model does pretty well and corresponds to a car that has a highway mph of about 25 mpg.  Notice that at high speeds we are seeing the scaling we expect due to air drag alone, for at high speed our operating costs are dominated by air resistance, but it was useful to create the simple model and do the fit in this case because the region of interest is in the overlap region.

### Per hour

Now that we know how the efficiency of our car varies with speed, knowing the average price of gas of $\$3.752$/gallon (from [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=price%20of%20gas)) we can compute the cost to operate an average car at a given speed:

[image: Operating cost of vehicle versus speed]

An in particular, we can compute the additional cost per hour per 5mph increase in speed as a function of speed:

[image: Additional operating cost for a 5 mph increase as a function of speed]

### Per 10 miles

Here I've shown the operating costs as a function of the time spent driving, so as to give costs per hour, which I think is useful for longer drives and something people have a handle on from other areas of life.

If we instead want to look at it as function of the distance travelled, we can look at the car efficiency as the cost to travel 10 miles as a function of speed.

[image: Operating cost per 10 miles]

Or we can consider again the change created by a 5 mph increase in speed for a fixed travel distance.

[image: Change in operating cost per 10 miles per 5 mph difference]

Where here it becomes clear that for a fixed travel distance, as long as you are going less than 40 miles per hour (which for our model was the maximum fuel efficiency speed, and varies per car but the data seems to indicate is about 40 mph across the board), you can always justify speeding by 5 mph from purely economic terms, but at something like highway speeds, it costs you an additional 15 cents or so per 10 miles to go 5 over.

### Traffic Lights

So, up till now we have considered the effectiveness of speeding from an economic perspective in the limit that we are travelling unimpeded down the road.  As people have requested in the comments, let's try to figure out how effective speeding is in a more city type environment.  This is a difficult problem to address, as traffic lights can have fairly complicated controllers.  In particular, in some regions there are [Green waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_wave) where the lights are designed to allow people travelling at the proper speed to pass unimpeded down long stretches of road.  Obviously in this case, you would want to travel at the speed of the green wave and speeding wouldn't help you and would in fact hurt you.

But, sophisticated traffic light controllers are not all that common outside of rich large cities.  So, let's try to adopt a *spherical cow* type approximation to traffic lights and assume that traffic lights are independent and just operating on some fixed cycle of green and red. $p$ will be the fraction of time the average traffic light is green, $\tau$ will be the length of a red light, $d$ will be the average distance between traffic lights.  If the lights are all operating independently, the distribution of waiting times when we reach a light can be modeled as
$$ P(t) = p \delta(t) + \frac{1}{\tau} ( 1 - p ) \quad 0 \leq t \leq \tau $$ or in words, with probability $p$ we don't have to wait at all, otherwise our waiting time will be uniform up to $\tau$.  This distribution has mean and variance
$$ \mu = \frac{\tau}{2} ( 1 - p ) $$
$$ \sigma^2 = \frac{\tau^2}{12} ( 1 - p) ( 3 p + 1 ) $$

Now, if we travel for $N$ blocks, we will have for the average time it takes
$$ \langle t \rangle = N \left( \frac{d}{v} + \frac{\tau}{2} ( 1 - p ) \right) $$
$$ \sigma^2_t = N \frac{\tau^2}{12} ( 1- p) ( 3 p + 1 ) $$ 
where we have added in the travel time between the lights themselves.

So, for instance, with $d = 1/10$ mile between lights on average, $\tau = 30$ seconds, and $p = 0.65$ we get for an average city speed as function of target speed:
[image: Average city speed versus target speed]

So, for a target speed of about 45 mph for a major road in a city, we get for an average speed something like 28 mph, which seems to agree moderately well with [observations](http://infinitemonkeycorps.net/projects/cityspeed/).

Now, as we have modeled it, if you speed you will get there faster, but what we should compare against is the intrinsic variability introduced by the traffic lights, and a case could be made that speeding 5 mph over is really only worth it if the gains you get in timing are larger than the natural variations in times you would have given the lights, otherwise you'll hardly notice the effect.  So in particular, we can compare the fractional reduction in your travel time for going 5 mph over, versus the fractional change in your travel time due to the intrinsic variation due to the random light timings $(\sigma/\mu)$ for different number of blocks.  We obtain:

[image: Speeding versus light variations]

Here the solid line shows the fractional change in your travel time you'd get by going 5 mph over the target speed at the bottom.  Notice that it scales as $1/v$ just as the very top of the post.  The dotted lines show fractional change in travel time induced by a 1 sigma variation in the behavior of the traffic lights, for different number of blocks.  Notice that at around 40 mph, the time you would shave off by going 5 mph is comparable to the natural variations you would expect in travel times due to your luck with the traffic lights if you are travelling 10 blocks, and both of these are at about the 10% level.  At this point it starts to become difficult to justify speeding as its effect will be hard to notice over the natural variation.  But, notice that if you are travelling a longer distance, there is a clear gain given by speeding, as the variations in travel time start to be suppressed through averaging.  On the flip side, for very short trips of a few blocks, the variations in your travel time given by your luck at the lights completely dominates any gain you'd get by speeding.

[image: Speeding gains in urban environment going 50 in a 45]

Here I've simulated traveling for 5, 15 or 50 blocks according to our model, both at 45 mph and going 50 mph.  I ran the simulation 10,000 times and here I show the time gained from speeding in different trials. Here we can really see that there are no noticeable gains for going 5 over over 5 blocks, it's completely washed out by our luck with the lights, but a noticeable change in our expected time over 50 blocks.

The code used for this answer is available as an [ipython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/alexalemi/346d54a6d79276f4fded)

*Addendum:* I've explore a more realistic model of power losses in cars in this [more recent answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/can-a-car-get-better-mileage-driving-over-hills/177676#177676)

Comment: You have one chart that shows that going faster *improves* efficiency at slow speeds, and another that claims going faster *always* costs more...

Comment: @ChrisWhite from my reading of the graphs (I may be wrong) the efficiency improvement is a marginal increase where as the cost increase is total cost. i.e. the cost of accelerating from 60 to 65 mph is less than the cost of accelerating from 55 to 60 mph BUT the total cost of travelling at 65 is always greater than the total cost of travelling at 60.

Comment: @MD-Tech I see what's going on. Traveling 20 miles per hour is *always* better than traveling 10 miles per hour to get somewhere. Period. alemi, your second two plots show cost per hour, which is... not really useful in the real world. People (outside of LA) travel to get somewhere, not for the sake of being in their cars for a prescribed amount of time. Really, though, this is all tangential to what the OP asked - the question as phrased has nothing to do with fuel economy.

Comment: As Chris says the actual interesting question is "If I drive 100 km how much more money do I spend and how faster do I arrive" - this is slightly different to what's answered here, since driving faster means we also spend less time on the road which offsets some costs.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I disagree, cost per hour can be quite useful. I'm used to driving at least an hour to get anywhere of interest and I'm pretty sure my world is real.

Comment: *"it costs you an additional $1.50 an hour to go 5 mph over the speed limit"* - That depends on the speed-limit... Also, cost-per-hour is a complete red-herring, what's important is cost-per-mile.  No one goes out and drives for a specific time, they drive a specific distance.  -1

Comment: So saving five minutes costs \$1.50 - do this 12 times and you've saved one hour and spent \$18. If you cost your company more than $18 an hour, you should really be speeding when on company time.

Comment: One place where going faster would save you money is if you're using the Air Conditioner. Its load (fuel consumption _rate_) is basically dependent on temperature and humidity. Assuming they are more or less constant for the duration of the trip, getting there faster would mean running the AC for a shorter time, thus consuming less fuel _for that purpose_. You still have the penalty for drag.

Comment: Seeing that the question asks for "insights or calculations" and specifically in the title asks "how effective" speeding is, I see this answer as exactly on-topic. Costing more money is one of the "effects".

Comment: I've added a section that looks at the cost on a per mile basis.  I originally did the calculation on a per hour basis because I was considering mostly highway type driving where you are driving for long times at constant speed, for which the difference in travel time is negligible.  Additionally people have a natural scale for dollars per hour to compare against from everyday life.  But, for low speeds, I admit this is misleading, so I added the corresponding plots rated by distance.

Comment: There is an analysis very similar to this one at http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/april12014/index.html

Comment: Your question went into great detail about cost, but didn't address the speed question in relation to stop lights, traffic, and so on. If I speed between stop lights, but the slower drivers behind me always catch up, I gain no time. But if I slip through one light, then I'm one light ahead.

Comment: I'm with the people saying that this answer, while well-organized and pretty, doesn't address the question. The asker is specifically wondering how much *time* (not money) you can save by speeding, *when taking into account the flow of traffic*. This answer simply doesn't consider that context.

Comment: @HenryKeiter  I've added a spherical cow type stab at modelling traffic lights.  I don't think canonical flow models will help here.  They are interested in jamming behavior and overall flow rates as a function of traffic density and are typically single lane simulations for which speeding doesn't help at all since you can't pass the person in front of you.  But, I think studying the *effectiveness* of speeding by considering the economics of fuel use is appropriate given the question at the top is "How effective is speeding?"

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer again.

Comment: @HenryKeiter mmmm the OP mentioned traffic tickets. What if alemi, in his answer, came to the conclusion that the additional costs of speeding would actually exceed that of a traffic ticket in a matter of days? I think his analysis is relevant and very interesting.

Comment: @alemi I like it. I'd like it even more if you took a shot at modeling traffic flow, but you've already got my +1 at this point.

Comment: Another interesting question is how much time do you lose from having to refill more often. That is, the time that you are saving is also being, at least, partly consumed by having to stop for gas more often.

Comment: @alemi , where did you get all these graphs? Are they from a research paper or did you just simulate them using a program?

Comment: @krismath [here you go](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/alexalemi/346d54a6d79276f4fded), an ipython notebook of the code to do the calculations and generate the plots.  Its a bit messy, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the effect on one driver you might consider the effect on traffic in general, that is what happens when everyone breaks the speed limit. As far as fluid dynamics is concerned, the side-effects of your speeding (if any) are felt by the people behind you.

Reaction distance increases linearly with speed, but stopping distance must include a term proportional to the square of speed, since with constant deceleration we know $v^2 = u^2 + 2as$

"Official" stopping distances are nominal anyway, since even under fixed driving conditions they don't account for variation among cars. However, the UK government defines "braking distance" as $v^2 * k$ where $k$ is 0.015 metres / mph<sup>2</sup> [I know, we're not fully on the metric system either], then rounds it.

- total stopping distance at 65mph: 83m
- total stopping distance at 70mph: 96m

This means that if cars separate themselves by the stopping distance (which in point of fact they don't, but *if*), then this 7.7% speed increase increases separation by 15.7%, so in a given time 8% fewer cars pass any given point per lane of traffic. Faster traffic reduces the capacity of the road.

In fact cars don't separate themselves by the stopping distance (or even by a fixed fraction of it), so what actually happens is some trade-off between reduced capacity, and the whole system becoming more reliant on people's reaction times, which are not entirely reliable. This is somewhat more dangerous, but even assuming no collisions it still has an effect on overall progress of the traffic. Drivers are more likely to have to stamp on the anchors when the person in front of them does something surprising, because they're driving proportionally closer to their pure reaction distance.

This is one area where the fluid dynamics comes in. Sudden braking causes the person behind you to do the same, which transforms smooth (laminar) flow of traffic into turbulent flow. *Much* less traffic gets through the same point, and traffic backs up behind it. It's even said that just changing lanes in fast congested traffic has a certain chance of causing traffic *to come to a halt* some time later and of course many cars behind you. Once one of these spontaneous no-reason traffic jams has formed, they persist for quite a long time and slow down everyone's journey. I don't have figures on the magnitude of the effect, though.

All that said, I don't think 65/70/75mph is the critical region in congested traffic. The UK uses realtime variable speed limits more like 50mph to improve total throughput on congested roads. So the difference between 65 for everyone and 70 for everyone is likely negligible, since 65 already causes lots of turbulence when the road is "full". You'll likely find it almost impossible in a temporary speed limit to do any speed other than the same as everyone else, which is kind of the idea.

[Edit: for economists, this is an inefficient market. Each driver benefits from driving slightly faster, but loses if everyone drives slightly faster. They "should" all contract to stick to some speed below the fixed limit, but don't have the means to do so. Only the owner of the road (the government) has the information to choose a "better" limit (closer to a Pareto-optimal point) or the means to communicate it to the drivers. Hypothetical private roads of course could likewise impose whatever T&Cs they chose on drivers, including banning or surcharging them for failing to follow anti-congestion measures, and arguably *might* be more responsive to customer feedback than the government is :-)]

Comment: A city traffic center (I don't remember which one) stated that a congestion slowdown during rush hour has lasted 3 hours after the initial event.

Answer (score 5):

If the speed limit is 60 mph, it would take 60 min to go 60 miles. To go the same 60 miles at 65 mph, it takes 55.4 minutes. A time savings of 4.6 minutes. Is it really worthwhile to speed if all you are going to save is a few minutes (even less for shorter distances).

Comment: To avoid hard calculations: Distance = time * speed. So 65 minutes at 60mph and 60 minutes at 65mph cover the exact same distance, no calculator needed.

Comment: @gnasher729 Do you take a different route to get somewhere just so you can drive faster?

Comment: @LDC3: no, he's taking a different (5 mile longer) route in order to make the calculation easier when comparing the two speeds, not in order to drive faster :-)

Answer (score 4):

Fluid dynamics models might have a practical value in heavily congested areas, but then you can't speed, save for some random short bits after traffic signals, rendering it irrelevant. Guess they're more of a traffic distribution models, smaller roads will attract more traffic if the counterpressure (congestion) gets higher on the main pipe (road).

It really depends on if you can keep the average speed higher, which is unintuitively hard. If you're driving far away, driving faster can make a big difference. On 400 mile trips on 60 mph roads even constant +5 mph would save about half an hour, assuming you can keep the average up. I don't know if your trucks are limited to 50 mph (80 kph), but overtaking one at the beginning could likewise save 1 h 20 min.

In partially congested areas where you can occasionally drive at +5, but then spend the same proportion of time behind someone at the limit, the average speed is less than +2.5. Say, your trip is 25 miles, and you spend in total 15 minutes at 50 mph (covering half the distance), and in between those sections drive at 55 mph, you get to your destination only 1 min 20 seconds earlier, and the average is under 52.4 mph (in reality even a bit lower, because your speed doesn't change instantly 50->55.

If the limit is still lower, and there are signal controlled intersections, the local conditions start to be more important. If you know the extra speed on some section will save you one red light, or that happens by chance (either by being there just before the light changes, or by having a better position in the queue so you don't have to stop twice), you might save an extra 30-90 seconds for each such intersection. If the same 25 mile trip is in a 40 mph zone, and you stop in 10 red lights for 40 seconds each time, your average speed is 33.9 (assuming instant speed change). Had you gone 45 and avoided the last three red lights, the average would depend on the distance from the 7th signals to the destination; with evenly spaced signals the average could be 41.6 mph - assuming you would have had to wait more (65 seconds, so it's plausible such a road could exist) in the first seven signals, i.e. you'd have passed on the same signal cycle. That's 44 minutes vs. 36 minutes. In an extreme case, if the signals are far apart enough and the +5 helps you avoid a stop in all of them, you'd get to your destination in just over 33 minutes. Usually, though, they try to time the signals close to each other so that any "reasonable" speeding won't get you through consecutive signals any faster than those who catch up with you on the next green cycle from the previous signals. Likewise, if going +5 would have gotten you past some other three signals on the way, depending on how or if their timing is interconnected and how long the cycles are, whether the guy going 40 would be there even within the same signal cycle of the last traffic signals + time difference from those signals to the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

[Preamble not really answering the question: Sounds almost like a classical philosophy question. To turn it around, you might ask whether its worth travelling at the speed limit of 5mph slower. And  5 mph slower than that. Or should you just walk? "]

The accepted answer computes the time saving and the fuel cost.

In the airline industry, this is formalised by defining the "airline cost index". This the ratio 'price of time' divided by 'price of fuel' and is an input to the flight management computer.

So, ignoring the legal issues around the speed limit, the drag equation means that the higher the price of time, the faster we should go.

It seems to me the same applies when driving a car.

Saving 5 minutes to get to a party running all evening is different to saving 5 minutes so as to get to a job interview on time, or getting someone to a hospital.

On top of that are the safety issues. Breaking distance is roughly quadratic in speed, so a 10% speed increase means a 20% increase in braking distance. This is turn relates to your question about "where you speed". Speeding just to get through lights might not be the safest place to do so.